# Tips on getting started writing a Roslyn analyzer for this case

Tags: c#

Consider the following classes...

```csharp
public abstract class Option<T>
{
    public T Value { get; protected set; }
}

public sealed class Some<T> : Option<T>
{
    public Some(T value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }
}

public sealed class None<T> : Option<T>
{
}

public sealed class Error<T> : Option<T>
{
    /*
    * Error related information would go here.
    */
}
```

The `Some<T>`, `None<T>`, and `Error<T>` classes would be used to represent the three possible kinds of result from a method (data access or otherwise).

We'd have a method similar to the following example that would return the base `Option<T>` type in order to allow any of the possible kinds of result to come from the method.

```csharp
public Option<string> GetSomeContrivedResult()
{
    /*
    * Method implementation here...
    */
}
```

The idea would be to have a Rosyln analyzer enforce the handling of the three possible kinds of result.  So for example, the following code would be in error because it doesn't handle each of the possible kinds of result from the `GetSomeContrivedResult` method.

```csharp
public void ContrivedMethod()
{
    var result = GetSomeContrivedResult(); // Error would be expected here.

    Console.WriteLine(result.Value);
}
```

The following example would be "in compliance" with the "rule" that all three possible kinds of result are handled.

```csharp
public void ContrivedMethod()
{
    var result = GetSomeContrivedResult();

    switch(result)
    {
        case Some<string> s:
            Console.WriteLine(s.Value);
            break;

        case None<string> n:
            Console.WriteLine("Nothing here.");
            break;

        case Error<string> e:
            Console.WriteLine("Some kind of non-exception error happened.");
            break;
    } 
}
```

I've been looking into creating a Roslyn analyzer that would raise an error or warning in the event that the `Option<T>` wasn't "correctly" handled, but as of yet I'm having trouble figuring out if what I want to do is even possible.

In terms of creating an analyzer to do this kind of analysis where should I start?

Answer (score 2):

I think you're overcomplicating it.

Simply make Value private, and *require* the consumer to use an inbuilt method (might I suggest `Select`) In order to extract the value, since `Option` is effectively the same thing as a list which can contain at most one element.  Otherwise you can use pattern matching to cast to the correct type.

In most languages which use Monads such as these, you would typically use a seperate type for `Error<T>` and `Option<T>`, because not every function which may or may not return a result can also return an error, and not every function which could return an error would otherwise ever not return a result.  Consider:

```
public Error<T> Divide(int x, int y) => x / y;
```

This function can return an error if `y` is 0, but otherwise you should never get a `None` back, so how would you even handle that case?

The real issue you could run into with C# is that a function marked as returning an `Option<T>` actually returns a null, unless you make sure you have nullable reference types turned on.